# Is there a way to specify infinite allowed lateness in Apache Beam?

Tags: apache-beam

I'm using fixed windows to batch data by event time in order to send it to an external API efficiently (batches of 60 seconds), accumulation mode is set to DISCARDING because it doesn't matter if late data is sent to the external API without the previous data.

Is it possible to specify an infinite allowed lateness, so late data is never discarded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is definitely possible, you can set allowed lateness to a very high `Duration` (for instance, `Duration.standardDays(36500)`). On the other hand , doing so would result in your state growing indefinitely, which might not be what you want. Every open window (every window ever seen) will have at least a timer called a GC timer - a timer set for the end of the window + allowed lateness. Every timer has to be kept in state and therefore, the size of your state will grow over time.
If you do not need batching based on event-time, it might be a better option to use [GroupIntoBatches](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.0.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/GroupIntoBatches.html), which should not suffer from this problem (you don't need to set allowed lateness and the size of your state will not grow).