# When to use windowing against grouping by event time?

Tags: apache-beam

[Kind of related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68191367/is-there-a-way-to-specify-infinite-allowed-lateness-in-apache-beam), as allowing infinitely late data would also solve my problem.

I have a pipeline linked to a pub/sub topic, from which data can come *very* late (days) as well as nearly real time: I have to make simple parsing and aggregation tasks on it, based on event time.

As each element holds a timestamp of the event time, my first idea when looking at the programming guide was to use [windowing by setting the timestamp on event time](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#adding-timestamps-to-a-pcollections-elements).

However, as the processing can happen a long time after the event, I would have to allow very late data, which based on the answer of the first link I posted seems to not be such a good idea.

An alternative solution I have come up with would be to simply group the data based on event time, without marking it as a timestamp, and then calculate my aggregates based on such a key. As the data for a given even time tend to arrive at the same time in the pipeline, I could then just provide windows of arbitrary length based on processing time so that my data is ingested as soon as it is available.

This got me wondering: does that mean that windowing is useless as soon as your data comes a bit later than real time ? Would it be possible to start a window when the first element is received and close it a bit afterwards ?

Comment: what is your source? if your source is pubsub, then you will not have much guarantees in terms of watermarks -but if it's Kafka, for instance, you should not have a lot of concern for out-of-order, extremey-late events

Comment: I am not sure I get what you mean: I am using pubsub, however data can arrive very late whichever the pipeline is ?